# Saving output to a csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Trying to save the output to a csv file. Below prints the information to the screen fine but when I try to save it to a csv or text file, I get one letter at a time. Trying to understand why.

```py
data = json.loads(response.text)
info = data['adapterInstancesInfoDto']
for x in range(len(info)):
     val = info[x]['resourceKey']['name']
     print(val)
```

Tried writing to a csv and text file same issue. Tried Pandas same result. I am thinking I need to convert it into a tuple or diction to save to a csv file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Below prints the information to the screen fine but when I try to save it to a csv or text file, I get one letter at a time." Why not show **the code that doesn't work**, instead of the code that does? We can't possibly explain a problem in something that we can't see. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in module `csv` for working with csv files:

Here's a example for writing to the file:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:

    writer = csv.writer(file)

    writer.writerow(["SNo", "Name"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Python"])
    writer.writerow([2, "Csv"])
```